# Openstack glance not working

Tags: openstack

My env is centos 6.5, python 2.7.8. I installed python-novaclient and python-glanceclient. I have sourced the openrc file and have the following envs

```
OS_REGION_NAME=xxx
OS_TENANT_ID=xxx
OS_PASSWORD=xxx
OS_AUTH_URL=https://keystone.example.com:5000/v2.0
OS_USERNAME=xxx
OS_TENANT_NAME=xxx
```

nova is working. I can have

```
$ nove list
------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | Name | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks  |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+-------------+--
| d28fa2f9-0e64-477b-9713-18bdd085ff92 | cloud2b | ACTIVE | - ...
```

however I cannot have glance working

```
$ glance image-list
Unable to establish connection to http://localhost:5000/v2.0/tokens
```

Is there something I did wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common error in deployment of glance

Export the OS_AUTH_URL with "https://keystone.example.com:35357/v2.0"

edit the /etc/glance/glance-api.conf  and /etc/glance/glanceregistry.conf files under

[ keystone_authtoken ] section and change the

auth_url to same

Comment: I tried that. But it didn't work. I actually had to install `glance-api` to actually get a `/etc/glance/glance-api.conf` it still tries localhost.